# How to get ElementTree to output tabs etc in attribute values as numerical entities?

Tags: python, elementtree

I run into a problem when using ElementTree to generate an XML file. Due to XML rules regarding white space in attributes, all white space characters in attributes will be normalized to space when parsing an XML file. But numerical entities will not. So, to have a tab, `\x09`, or for example `\x0d\x0a`, in an attribute value in the in-memory representation of XML, the XML file must contain `&#9;` or `&#13;&#10;` respectively.

But ElementTree will serialize only the `\x0a` character as numerical entity, but not e.g. `\x09` and `\x0d` -- they will end up as the actual tab or cr characters in the XML file, and any conforming XML processor, including ElementTree itself, will then read back normal spaces, so roundtripping is impossible.

Can there be anything done about this? Except not using ElementTree for writing the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML does not support most control characters, not even as entities.  See the [W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204/), and look for the `Char` production.

You need to encode the information.  Base64 encoding is the most usual.

Comment: Thanks, I see, but this only eliminates the "etc" part. As \x09, \x0A, \x0D would allowed, and in principle, just not with ET, roundtripable (as entities).

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Apparently, the standard is not interpreted 100% the same by different implementations.  This is probably an ET bug.  Did you check in their web site?